# Why is it 'quanto è lungo' instead of 'quanto lungo è'?

Tags: grammar, sentences, word-order

When asking, for example, **how long is the bridge**.

Intuitively I'd say, *Quanto lungo è il ponte*. However, the correct translation seems to be *Quanto è lungo il ponte*.

Why is it *Quanto è lungo ...* instead of *Quanto lungo è ...*?

Comment: Both forms are  correct.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: @Hachi: _Quanto lungo..._ sounds a bit off to me. Do you have in mind some context in which it could sound natural?

Comment: ...ma quanto lungo è questo ponte?

Comment: @Hachi: Personalmente non mi suona molto, ma sarà una questione di italiani regionali, idioletti etc.

Comment: Mario disse "Il ponte è lungo!"; Luigi chiese "Quanto lungo è?"

Comment: Thanks for the insightful comments, so basically both forms are correct but the difference is mostly in 'style' and/or 'emphasis'?

e.g. I'd say 'quanto lungo è' if i'm trying to put emphasis on the length and 'quanto è lungo' if the question is more generic.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica The situation is a bit different, because there is nothing after *è* in the question. In the case Luigi wants to put emphasis on “quanto”, the sentence has to be “*Quanto* è lungo?”

Comment: @ShiftyF97: As an Italian, I'd never say such a sentence as *Quanto lungo è questo ponte?, emphasis or not, and were I to hear or read it, I'd think that the utterer is a foreigner. As egreg says, for emphasis you use different, partial phrasings.

Comment: Analogously, to pay a compliment (or an insult) to someone you can say _Quanto sei bello!_ (or _Quanto sei stupido!_), while inverting the verb and the adjective wouldn't work.

Comment: @DaG I have to disagree: the form “Quanto bello sei!” has nothing strange to my ear.

Comment: @egreg: It might be another of those Northern-Central-Southern Italy things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a (very) broad sense, the order of phrase elements in Italian is quite free, sometimes leading
to slightly strange utterances, up to never heard ones, but still understandable. Undoubtedly there
is a standard and clean order, more used in "controlled" text found in books or, generally, written text.

But when coming to spoken phrases, especially in dialogs, things can change a lot: elements can be dropped,
leaving them implicit, and the order can be changed to put emphasis somewhere, normally the first word. Lastly,
redundancy sometimes happens, like the famous "a me mi piace". The mechanism for this last sentence can be
the following: a speaker is asked about what it likes, and the first concept that arises in its mind is "a me",
because the speaker is replying, speaking about itself; but, after that, the very common phrase "mi piace"
should be changed to simply "piace", but perhaps is too late, and "a me mi piace" comes out.

About "*Quanto è lungo*", in a spoken dialog the phrase can turn to "*Quanto lungo è*" because the listener,
not satisfied, wants to now "*how much* long" ("quanto lungo") at first. The dialog can be:

> Mario: "Questo ponte è molto lungo"
>   Luigi: "Quanto?" (neutral)
>   ...or "Sì, ma quanto?" (concessive)
>   ...or "Sì, ma quanto lungo?" (impatient)
>   ...or "Sì, ma quanto lungo è?" (even more impatient)

** UPDATE **
A comment says that in the above phrases the subject is implicit, and this would change the situation. Let's see how it would sound with an explicit subject:

> "Sì, ma quanto lungo è questo ponte?"
>   ...or "Sì, ma quanto lungo è questo benedetto ponte?!" (substitute *benedetto* with something more appropriate, and write the whole phrase in capital letters)

or even

> "E quanto lungo sarebbe questo ponte?" (sceptic)

which would sound the same as if it was:

> "E quanto sarebbe lungo questo ponte?"

I think that the subject, implicit or not, does not matter.

In this dialog, the phrase "Quanto è lungo?" would not transmit the sense of impatience. In live dialogs,
stresses on words can help, but even without stresses and/or prosody the above phrases are clearly impatient,
at least to me.

The following two searches by Ngram Viewer show how common are the "standard" constructions versus
the "colloquial" ones:

["quanto è lungo"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quanto%20lungo%20%C3%A8%2Cquanto%20%C3%A8%20lungo&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquanto%20lungo%20%C3%A8%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cquanto%20%C3%A8%20lungo%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bquanto%20%C3%A8%20lungo%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BQuanto%20%C3%A8%20lungo%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cquanto%20lungo%20%C3%A8%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cquanto%20%C3%A8%20lungo%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bquanto%20%C3%A8%20lungo%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BQuanto%20%C3%A8%20lungo%3B%2Cc0) is about 10-20 times more common.

["quanto è grande"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quanto%20grande%20%C3%A8%2Cquanto%20%C3%A8%20grande&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cquanto%20grande%20%C3%A8%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bquanto%20grande%20%C3%A8%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BQuanto%20grande%20%C3%A8%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cquanto%20%C3%A8%20grande%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bquanto%20%C3%A8%20grande%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BQuanto%20%C3%A8%20grande%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Cquanto%20grande%20%C3%A8%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bquanto%20grande%20%C3%A8%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BQuanto%20grande%20%C3%A8%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cquanto%20%C3%A8%20grande%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bquanto%20%C3%A8%20grande%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BQuanto%20%C3%A8%20grande%3B%2Cc0) is only about 3 times more common.

Comment: You're focusing on something that's quite far from the topic: when the subject is implied, like in all the dialog questions, the situation is very different from a plain question, which is what the OP is asking for. Not worth a downvote, just a comment.

Comment: @egreg I've updated the answer. It seems to me that the implicit/explicit subject does not change the ultimate meaning of the phrases.

Answer (score 2):

As a Central Italian, I find any construction of the form *quanto* + adjective + verb *essere* to be very strange-sounding, both in interrogative and exclamative sentences. I trust other commenters who find them utterable, and even so in limited contexts, but I'd attribute it more to regional differences than to colloquial or emphatic registers.

To source this, lest it remain an I-say-so thing, apparently neither [Treccani dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/quanto1) nor the [Grande dizionario della lingua italiana](http://www.gdli.it/sala-lettura/vol-xv/15) (we are interested here in *Quanto*<sup>2</sup>, starting at the end of p. 63), nor [De Mauro's dictionary](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/quanto), nor Zingarelli (behind a paywall) seem to record anything of the form “*quanto* + adjective + verb *essere*”.

My temporary conclusion (which I'll be ready to change if new evidence appears) is that that form is acceptable – in suitable contexts – in some Northern varieties of Italian, but not in Standard Italian.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised you find them strange, because to me they sound not only utterable, but even extremely natural and sometimes preferred (when one wants to put the emphasis on the adjective). I wonder if there is some study of their geographical distribution.

Comment: It's possible that my acceptance of *Quanto bello sei!* is due to my local language where the sentence would be *Che beo che te si!*. But I perceive a difference in emphasis between *Quanto bello sei!* and *Quanto sei bello!*, However this is a different situation than the plain *Quanto è lungo il ponte?*

Comment: @egreg in my answer there is a link which shows that "quanto grande è" has a number of occurences not really neglectable in respect to "quanto è grande". Of course, one should ask what texts are analyzed by google, "lot of books" is not very clear.